# How to filter values in a Django form using ModelForm?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

The problem is that I have a model secciones that is associated with a user and a productos model that is also associated with a user and model secciones,

```
class secciones(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   user = models.ForeignKey(User)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(secciones, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class productos(models.Model):
    user        = models.ForeignKey(User)
    secciones   = models.ForeignKey(secciones)
    name        = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    image       = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'productos')
    precio      = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)
    descripcion = models.TextField(max_length=300, null=True,blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(productos, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __unicode__(self):
       return self.name
```

I am creating a form so that the user can enter a new product in the productos model, but I just want to leave the sections of the model secciones of the user that I log in

This is the view

```
def agregar_producto(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        modelform = AgregarProducto(request.POST,request.FILES)
        print modelform
        if modelform.is_valid():
            modelform.save()

        return redirect("/editar-perfil/")
    else:
        modelform = AgregarProducto()
    return render(request, "home/AgregarProducto.html", {"form":modelform})
```

This is the form

```
class AgregarProducto(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model   = productos
```

How can I get the form to display only the sections of the model secciones of the user that logged in

Comment: It is better to give english names to classes and functions when you ask something on SO (actually always). And following PEP8 is a good practice too. Could you please explain what does it mean: `leave the sections of the model secciones`?

Answer (score 4):

Override the `__init__` method of your model, and set the queryset for your `secciones` field.

```
class AgregarProducto(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model   = productos

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop('user')
        super(AgregarProducto, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['secciones'].queryset = secciones.objects.filter(user=user)
```

Now update your view so that you pass the `user` when instantiating the form. You need to do this for GET and POST requests.

```
if request.method == "POST":
    modelform = AgregarProducto(request.POST, request.FILES, user=request.user)
    ...
else:
    modelform = AgregarProducto(user=request.user)
```

You can use the `login_required` decorator, so that only logged in users can access the view.

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def agregar_producto(request):
```

Finally, please rename your models to `Secciones` and `Productos`. The lowercase `secciones` and `productos` look very unusual to most Django users, and can be confused with model instances.

Comment: Thanks for the reply friend, but now I have the following error.                                                                                                         KeyError at /agregar-producto/

'user'                                                                                                          Exception Location:  /home/scorpiotx100/Documentos/project/minegocio1_7/minegocio/minegocio/apps/home/forms.py in __init__, line 18

Comment: There was a mistake in my code before - if we use the `kwargs.pop('user')` approach, then we need `user=request.user` when instantiating the form.

Comment: Hi friend, now it works but when I register a new product I get the same error

Comment: I can't see how my code would cause that error. Please [edit] your original question and include the full traceback.

Comment: The form is working well, it is showing correctly the sections of the current user, the problem is that when I add a new product I get the error. In the forum I put the modifications that I did.

Comment: You haven't shown the traceback so I can't help any more. Hope you figure out the problem.